# How to use PowerShell to find and compare assembly versions

Tags: powershell

I’m new to Powershell and trying to create a script to search several files and find the version of a specific assembly, then compare that they are all the same. If they are not all the same, an exception is thrown.

I’m able to use Select-Sting to search the files and return the lines where the assembly’s name is found.

```
$resultStrings = (Get-ChildItem -path ".\packages.config" -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern MyAssemblyName')
```

That returns a result like this. Note, the version may not always be in this order:

```
folder1\packages.config:11:  <package id="MyAssemblyName" version="2022.1.16.2" targetFramework="net461" />
folder2\packages.config:57:  <package id="MyAssemblyName" version="2022.1.19.1" targetFramework="net461" />
folder3\packages.config:15:  <package id="MyAssemblyName" version="2022.1.16.2" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Now, do I need to parse out the version numbers from each line to compare or can that be done with the existing results somehow?

EDIT: Turns out I only need to be concerned with comparing the assembly  versions in files that can be found under 2 specific folders.

```
".\web\folder1\SearchAllFoldersInHere\packages.config"
".\web\folder2\SearchAllFoldersInHere\packages.config"
```

Comment: it sounds like you should be using XmlDocument to get the values of `version=` instead of `Select-String`

Comment: you could use something like `$xml.SelectSingleNode('//package[@id="MyAssemblyName"]/@version').Value` to expand the value of `version` if using XmlDocument to read the config files however we need an example of a config file

Comment: Related. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/447901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex on structured markup - PowerShell can parse and manipulate XML documents just fine without it:

```
# discover the config files
$packagesConfigs = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter ".\packages.config" -Recurse 

# use Select-Xml + Select-Object to find and re-shape the relevant data 
$assemblyVersions = $packagesConfigs |Select-Xml -XPath '//package[@id = "MyAssemblyName"]/@version' |Select-Object Path,@{Name='Version';Expression={$_.Node.Value}}
```

You can then use `Group-Object` to group each occurrence based on the extracted version string:

```
# group by version string
$versionGroups = @($assemblyVersions |Group-Object Version)

if ($versionGroups.Count -gt 1) {
  # more than one version found
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias R. Jessen, this gets me closer but, please see my edit above. I only need to be concerned with searching files under 2 specific folders. The code you provided is unfortunately returning some unneeded values.  Also, once I have the all the versions, how would I compare that they are all the same?

Comment: @SimpleSimon You can do `Get-ChildItem -Path web\folder1,web\folder2 ...` instead of you want. The easiest way to find distinct versions is to pipe the results of the last command to `Group-Object Version` and then inspect how many resulting groupings it produces

Comment: How exactly would I inspect how many resulting groupings it produces? I've tried `$groupsCount = $packagesConfigs.Count` and then use it like `if ($groupsCount.Count > 1) {...}` but, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @SimpleSimon You appear to have skipped the `Group-Object` step - I've updated the answer